# Extract data inside an html element attribute (data-react-props) using Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, web-scraping, domcrawler, symfony-css-selector

I need to extract a json that is inside a page, more precisely in div inside the tag `data-react-props`

```
<div data-react-class="GamePageHeader" data-react-props="{"id":1274,"slug":[...]}
```

How can I extract the json inside the react props? I believe that with HtmlDomParser I can't do this.

---

Edit:

Thanks to Prateek's reply I wrote the code:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelectorConverter;

$html = file_get_html('https://www.igdb.com/games/simcity--2');
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$data = $crawler->filter('div[data-react-class="GamePageHeader"]')->attr('data-react-props');

print $data;
```

But I always get the error

```
LOG.error: Expecting a DOMNodeList or DOMNode instance, an array, a string, or null, but got "simple_html_dom".
```

I have installed packages `symfony/css-selector` and `symfony/dom-crawler` in Laravel 5.8

Comment: Please add code attempts.

Comment: Hi @aviya.developer, now it's ok?

Comment: Yeah great. Always add some code attempts to questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot do this using HtmlDomParser.
However, this can be done using symfomy's [dom crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#installation).

Step 1: Install it using `composer require symfony/dom-crawler`, also install [css-selector](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) using `composer require symfony/css-selector`

Step 2: Get the html and instantiate the crawler

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.igdb.com/games/simcity--2');
$crawler = new Crawler($html); // same as HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $html);
```

Step 3: Use filter to crawl through the body and get your required dom elements and use attr to get value insede the tag

```
$data = $crawler->filter('div[data-react-class="GamePageHeader"]')->attr('data-react-props');
```

Comment: To make the scrape in an url, do I have to put it like this? `$html = file_get_html('https://www.igdb.com/games/simcity--2')` Unfortunately I don't find much documentation. ps: I'm using Laravel if it can be useful

Comment: Yes you do need to use that line. also make sure you have added `use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;` to the class you are using it in. You will also need to require css selector package from symfony for the css selector in filter to work. `composer require symfony/css-selector` I;ve updated the answer to reflect that. Feel free to check out the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#usage).

Comment: I updated the question with your help but I still have problems

Comment: I saw you update, you can fix this by updating the initiation of $html variable, this can be fixed by either using `$html = file_get_html('https://www.igdb.com/games/simcity--2')->plaintext;` or an easier way would be to just use file_get_contents instead like `$html = file_get_contents('https://www.igdb.com/games/simcity--2');`, I also updated my answer to reflect that.